# How to overlay one Footer Widget background over Socket Div background?

Tags: html, css

I have my coding, i want to do little changes only using only Css but not getting my result.

Actually, i want to overlay the footer widget div over the socket div, but the socket div text "design by john doe" should be visible. Is it possible ?

in other words: The footer widget background be overwrite over the socket background but the socket text should be visible to user. Thanks

```css
#footer {
   animation-name: backgroundColorPalette;
   animation-duration: 19000ms;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-direction: alternate;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#footer {
   padding: 70px 0px;
   z-index: 1;
}

#socket {
   margin: auto;
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 5px 0px;
}

@keyframes backgroundColorPalette {
   0% {
      background-color: #ec008c;
   } 100% {
      background-color: #00bcc3;
   } 50% {
      background-color: #5fb26a;
   } 33.3% {
      background-color: #fc7331;
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
   <center><h2>Footer widgets</h2></center>
</div>

<div id="socket">
   <center><p>Design by John Doe</p></center>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want the footer div and the socket div to have the same background?

Comment: Not buddy, if i want to do that, i can easily assign the background css property, i actually want to overlap the footer widget over socket widget but the socket texts should be displayed, not the black background.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```css
#footer {
  animation-name: backgroundColorPalette;
  animation-duration: 19000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#footer {
  padding: 90px 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#socket {
  margin: auto;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 60px;
}
@keyframes backgroundColorPalette {
  0% {
background-color: #ec008c;
  }
  100% {
background-color: #00bcc3;
  }
  50% {
background-color: #5fb26a;
  }
  33.3% {
background-color: #fc7331;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="footer">
    <center>
      <h2>Footer widgets</h2>
    </center>
  </div>

  <div id="socket">
    <center>
      <p>Design by John Doe</p>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the idea is set `#socket` to have `position: relative` so we can move it upwards using `bottom: 60px` so it overlays the `#footer`. Then we can give `#socket` a transparent background.

I've also increased the padding of `#footer` so the footer div looks more like it does in your question.